# How to use GPIO19 and GPIO20 in esp32-S3

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I was trying to use the GPIO19 and GPIO20 in esp32-S3 but these pins always stay High, I tried disabling the TinyUSB driver in the esp-idf menuconfig but still, I was not able to use those pins as generic GPIOs. How can I do that?

I am using ESP-IDF with vsCode.

This is the code snippet:

```
#define CAM_PWR GPIO_NUM_20
    .......
    .......
gpio_pad_select_gpio(CAM_PWR);
gpio_set_direction (CAM_PWR, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
gpio_set_level(CAM_PWR, 0);
```

Comment: Please clean up the tags. This is not related to "esp8266". And most likely you are using the ESP-IDF framework and not the Arduino framework.